# JDBC Unreachable 'create statement' statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am currently making a programme that communicates with an SQL database, after I make a query I obviously have to close the connections, I can close the connection fine, but I cannot close the actual statement itself. Is this necessary to close or does it close because it is a function of the connection itself? The code works perfectly fine I was just curious if this statement was needed. Here is the code, there error is highlighted towards the end of the returnEmployeeSalary function:

```
public class GroundControlToMajorTom {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        System.out.println(returnEmployeeSalary("ivy"));

    }

    public static String returnEmployeeSalary(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        HashMap<String, String> infoHR = connectionInfoHR();

        String query = "SELECT salary FROM employees WHERE first_name = '" + name + "'";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(infoHR.get("url"), infoHR.get("uname"), infoHR.get("pass"));

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        rs.next();
        String id = rs.getString("salary");

        return id;

        st.close(); /////////// ERROR IS HERE /////////////
        con.close();
    }

    public static HashMap<String, String> connectionInfoHR() {
        HashMap<String, String> infoHR = new HashMap();

        infoHR.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sql_hr");
        infoHR.put("uname", "root");
        infoHR.put("pass", "");

        return infoHR;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have statements after the `return` statement. Given `return` ends the normal flow of a method, the subsequent close methods aren't executed.

However, your code doesn't take into account abrupt exits of a method through an exception. In such situation, you won't properly close resources like statements and connections.

The appropriate solution is to use try-with-resources. Your code would then look like:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(infoHR.get("url"), infoHR.get("uname"), infoHR.get("pass"));
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);) {

    rs.next();
    return rs.getString("salary");
}
```

At the end of the try-with-resources block, the result set, statement and connection will be closed, in the right order, even if closing of one of these fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your resultSet ,statement then your database connection to release all resources from the database.
try this :

```
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(infoHR.get("url"), infoHR.get("uname"), infoHR.get("pass"));
    try {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    try {
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

    try {

     rs.next();
     return rs.getString("salary");
    } finally {
    resultSet.close();
    }
    } finally {
    statement.close();
    }
    } finally {
    connection.close();
    }
```

You could follow this article for more information :
[How to Close JDBC Resources Properly – Every Time](https://shinesolutions.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/)

Update : 
Since Java 7 you could use this :

```
 try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(infoHR.get("url"), infoHR.get("uname"), infoHR.get("pass"));
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)) {

         rs.next();
         return rs.getString("salary");
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is a far better and less verbose option available since Java 7: try-with-resources.

Comment: Yes I know but he didn't specify which java version he's using so I shared a generic one here,I will update it thanks.

Comment: Java 8 is pretty much the baseline these days. Even expecting Java 7 is pushing it in my opinion.

Comment: Content is correct but it doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Hi guys, just a quick question. If I am using the database on my localhost, is it necessary to use try catch if I know the password, username and link will always be correct? These are projects for my portfolios so companies will see them. Cheers :)

Comment: Yes exception handling is mandatory with resources like database access, otherwise you will find yourself in situations where a lot of connections are opened in the background because an exception were thrown without closing the resources, imagine the situation of a wrong SQL query for example.